# Cannot import more than 10000 nodes in Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm trying to import data from a 50MB text file of Users and followers on Twitter to Neo4j. But my code only run till it reachs about 10000 nodes and throws Errors: "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded". Here is my code and I don't know where did I do wrong?

```
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    String currentLine;
    String token[] = null;

    try (Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx()) {
        Label userLabel = DynamicLabel.label("User");

        while((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if(!currentLine.equals("\n")) token = currentLine.split("\t");
            if(token.length > 2) {

                userNode = graphDb.createNode(userLabel);
                userNode.setProperty("username", token[2]);
                userNode.setProperty("id", token[1]);
                userNode.setProperty("cookie", token[0]);
                System.out.println("Insert user: " + token[0] + " " + token[1] + " " + token[2]);
                System.out.println("Insert follower...");

                for(int i=3;i<token.length;i++) {
                    followerNode = graphDb.createNode(userLabel);
                    followerNode.setProperty("id", token[i]);
                    relationship = userNode.createRelationshipTo(followerNode, RelTypes.FOLLOWED_BY);

                }
                System.out.println("Insert follower: done! - " + (token.length-3));

            }
        }

        tx.success();
    }

    br.close();
```

Comment: Batch your transactions, e.g. commit your tx every 10k users and then create a new tx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't with neo4j, it's with java. Specifically, your heap is exceeding the maximum size.

You can either:

a) optimize your code so that your heap doesn't get as big as it's getting (I'm usually not one to talk about optimization until later stages of development, but you've got to be wasting an awful lot of heap space somewhere, especially if your input file is only 50 MB)

b) run java with the following command line argument, which allows you to override the maximum heap size: `-Xmx1024m`. That would set it at 1024 MB, but you can replace `1024` with whatever you need.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I have set it at 1024 MB before I ask and it still throws the same errors. Maybe the problem is in my code.